# PostgreSQL invalid input syntax for type bigint

Tags: postgresql

I'm going through Anthony DeBarros's Practical SQL and am trying to import data using COPY but am getting the following error message:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "1.05076E+11"
CONTEXT:  COPY us_counties_2010, line 72, column area_land: "1.05076E+11".

Thanks

Comment: I know these problems from editing a csv-file with Excel.
Once you edit a csv-file via Excel that has big numbers, Excel tends to format them in scientific notation, what can be a big nuisance...

Comment: If you can't change the CSV file, then your only chance is to declare the column as `numeric` import the file, then change the column back to `bigint`. Or use a staging table to which you import the file first, the copy the data to the real table afterwards

Comment: @a_horse_with_name I'll give that a try!